# PHP echo array help

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [1197624] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [datetime] => 2010-11-06 21:32:56
                    [movieID] => 1197624
                    [personID] => 0
                    [filename] => 1197624.jpg
                    [more indexes]...
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [datetime] => 2010-11-06 21:25:53
                    [movieID] => 1197624
                    [personID] => 0
                    [filename] => 1197624.jpg
                    [more indexes]...
                )
        )
    [0987657] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [datetime] => 2010-11-06 21:38:07
                    [movieID] => 0
                    [personID] => 0987657
                    [filename] => 0987657.jpg
                    [more indexes]...
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [datetime] => 2010-11-06 21:55:09
                    [movieID] => 0
                    [personID] => 0987657
                    [filename] => 0987657.jpg
                    [more indexes]...
                )
        )
    [5467023] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [datetime] => 2010-11-06 21:59:33
                    [movieID] => 5467023
                    [personID] => 0
                    [filename] => 5467023.jpg
                    [more indexes]...
                )


        )
)
```

I want to echo it like this (notice how the keys are grouped):

```
<div>
  <img src="../1197624.jpg" />
  <p>1197624</p>
  <ul>
    <li>2010-11-06 21:32:56</li>
    <li>2010-11-06 21:25:53</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <img src="../0987657.jpg" />
  <p>0987657</p>
  <ul>
    <li>010-11-06 21:38:07</li>
    <li>2010-11-06 21:55:09</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <img src="../5467023.jpg" />
  <p>5467023</p>
  <ul>
    <li>02010-11-06 21:59:33</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $k => $vals) {
    echo "<div>\n";
    echo "  <img src=\"../" . $vals[0]["filename"] . "\" />\n";
    echo "  <p>" . $k . "</p>\n";
    echo "  <ul>\n";
    foreach ($vals as $v) {
        echo "    <li>" . $v["datetime"] . "</li>\n";
    }
    echo "  </ul>\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
}
```

A few assumptions here:

- Each element in the top-level array will have at least one element as its value (so that the filename for the `img` tag can be obtained from the first element).
- For each element of the top-level array, the filenames in the entry's values are identical (if not, the first one may not be the right one to choose).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to include also the HTML in your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The rough structure will look like this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $element)
 {
       ... echo opening div....

       echo $key; // 1197624
       ...
       echo $element[0]["datetime"]; // 2010-11-06 21:32:56
       echo $element[1]["datetime"]; // 2010-11-06 21:25:53
       ...

       ... echo closing div....


 }
```

Comment: Yes, but I dont know how many $element[0] are. I mean sometimes is $element[0] only and sometimes $element[786]

Comment: @Jonathan then do another `foreach` on them